# Google Drive Search : Folders created manually are not accessible using java code

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I have written code to search a folder on google drive using Drive API, but it seems if a folder is created manually on the drive, its not accessible to the code.

```
FileList result = drive.files().list().setQ("mimeType ='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'").execute();
```

In the results, I am getting only those folders which were created using the Drive API code below.

```
com.google.api.services.drive.model.File fileMetadata = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
fileMetadata.setTitle(folderName);
fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");
drive.files().insert(fileMetadata).execute();
```

Please advise where is the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using 'drive.file' scope. You should use either 'drive.metadata.readonly', 'drive.metadata', 'drive.readonly', or 'drive' scope.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/scopes

Comment: Thanks for the response, Please could you advise how to set the scope.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#web_server_applications

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java#step_3_set_up_the_sample